# How can I remove spam ad about some Kubernetes service (likely in MOTD) in Ubuntu 20.04, shown on each SSH login?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, configuration

On SSH login I get

```
 * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how MicroK8s
   just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cluster deployment.

   https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge
```

spam message.

How can I get rid of this spamware?

From https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu?tab=readme-ov-file#remove-dynamic-motd-spam it looks like it comes from MOTD - but method provided there apparently works on 23.04 while [not working on 20.04 and 22.04](https://github.com/Skyedra/UnspamifyUbuntu/issues/9).

Comment: I am not sure when exactly that MOTD is updated on the system, but IIRC it's done once a day, so it might take a day for it to vanish. Or you can update the MOTD manually after making the change.